# ShareThis opens up facebook share in a new window

Tags: javascript, html, css, sharethis

I am trying to use ShareThis widget for my sharing needs, so I have the following:

```
<span class='st_facebook_hcount' displayText='Facebook'></span>
<span  class='st_twitter_hcount' displayText='Tweet'></span>
<span class='st_plusone_hcount' displayText='Google +1'></span>
<span  class='st_email_hcount' displayText='Email'></span>

var switchTo5x=true;
                $.getScript("http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js", function(){
                    stLight.options({publisher: "c68c8f6c-c670-419b-b8e2-23772e22a861", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false, popup: 'false'});
                });
```

now the issue is that when I click on facebook it always opens up a new window. I've already mentioned that I wanted this in a popup. For Twitter it works just fine. Why is this? Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fvmLn/) to demo the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on their docs, [you can not achieve this](http://support.sharethis.com/customer/portal/questions/720321-sharing-data-opens-in-new-tab#sthash.ni0C1wPP.dpbs) unless the button they click on is the sharethis or email button.  If you do find a solution/hack, please let me know :-)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles across this, they have now added the ability to do this. Add servicePopup: true to your stLight.options.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
stLight.options({
  publisher: "YOUR PUBLISHER KEY",
  servicePopup: true
});
</script>
```